# Trace of log of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> How to prove that $$\operatorname{Tr}(\log B) = \sum_i \log b_i \tag{1}$$ where the $b_i$ are the eigenvalues of matrix $B$?

Question background:

1. This question arises from quantum field theory in particle physics. Where $B$ is $i\not\partial - m$ in continuous Hilbert space(this space of four dimensional spacetime). And $\not\partial=\partial_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}$, $\gamma^{\mu}$ is four dimensional [Dirac Gamma matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices), there also a four dimensional identity matrix with $m$. You can specify this as each point in Hilbert space, there is a four dimensional matrix， or each element of B is a four dimensional matrix in Hilbert space;
2. About logarithm of matrix definition, I use Peskin and Schroeder’s QFT book, they define the logarithm of matrix as Taylor series expansion.

Below is my navie attempt (sorry for my insufficient math knowledge), suppose $B$ can be diagonalized as:

$$B = U^{-1}\Lambda U \tag{2}$$

where $U$ is some unitary matrix and $\Lambda$ is diagonal matrix. Then

$$\operatorname{Tr} (\log B) = \operatorname{Tr} (\log (U^{-1}\Lambda U)) \tag{3}$$

I expect that

$$ \operatorname{Tr} (\log (U^{-1}\Lambda U)) = \operatorname{Tr} (\log (\Lambda)) \tag{4}$$

But how to proceed from ($3$)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you very much, I re-edit my question!

Comment: How are you defining $\log B$? Also, is $B$ normal, self-adjoint, positive-definite? Real, or complex? I notice that you assume $U$ is unitary, so it suggests normality at least, and probably a complex matrix, but it would be good to confirm.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for your comment, I will re-edit my question!

Comment: I'm still not sure how you're defining the logarithm of a matrix. If it's in the [continuous functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus) sense, then one can show that the process of diagonalising a normal matrix, applying $\log$ to each eigenvalue, and stitching the matrix back up satisfies the definition of the continuous functional calculus. This would $\log(U^{-1} \Lambda U) = U^{-1} \log(\Lambda) U$ follows immediately. Or maybe you're defining $\log B$ with a Taylor series? In that case, there are questions of convergence to worry about.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for your comment, actually, this come from a theoretical physics question. I apologize not offer enough information. I will re-edit my post!

Comment: If $\{b_k\}$ are the eigenvalues of $B$ then the eigenvalues of $f(B)$ are given by $\{f(b_k)\}$ for any analytic function $f$.  The definition of the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, therefore
$$Tr\big(f(B)\big) = \sum_kf (b_k)$$ The only issue to worry about is whether the function is single-valued on the original eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a complex function $f$ defined by a power series centred at some point $z_0 \in \Bbb{C}$, converging on some open disc $D$ centred at $z_0$. That is,
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z - z_0)^n$$
for all $z \in D$, for some sequence of coefficients $(a_n)$. We can then extend this definition to certain $m \times m$ matrices, by defining:
$$f(B) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (B - z_0I)^n.$$
Now, there is a matter of convergence here. The above will not necessarily converge for all matrices; it depends on the original series, or more precisely, its region of convergence. But, let's brush over that, and suppose that $f$ is not only well-defined at $B$, it is also continuous (the latter is not an unreasonable assumption).

Then, if $U$ is an invertible $m \times m$ matrix, we have:
\begin{align*}
U^{-1} f(B) U &= U^{-1} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (B - z_0I)^n\right) U \\
&= U^{-1} \left(\lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^N a_n (B - z_0I)^n\right) \right) U \\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(U^{-1}\left(\sum_{n=0}^N a_n (B - z_0I)^n\right) U\right) &\text{since $A \mapsto U^{-1} A U$ is continuous} \\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^N a_n U^{-1}(B - z_0I)^n U\right) &\text{since $A \mapsto U^{-1} A U$ is linear} \\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^N a_n \left(U^{-1}(B - z_0I)U \right)^n \right) &\text{since $(U^{-1} A U)^n = U^{-1} A^n U$, by induction} \\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^N a_n \left(U^{-1}BU - z_0I \right)^n \right) & \text{linearity again, and $U^{-1} I U = I$}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \left(U^{-1}BU - z_0I \right)^n = f(U^{-1} B U)
\end{align*}

This will work when $f$ is any Taylor series for the natural logarithm. All that is assumed is that $f(B)$ exists. If we assume $U$ diagonalises $B$, and take the trace of both sides, we get $(D)$, as required.

Answer (score 2):

The formula you seek to demonstrate is nothing but the formula for the determinant of the matrix exponential inversed.

Let $A$ be a $n\cdot n$ matrix, then

$$\det(\exp A) = \exp(\operatorname{Tr} A)$$

If we define $B = \exp(A)$, we obtain,

$$\ln(\det B) = \operatorname{Tr}(\ln B)$$

Since the determinant is independent of the base in which it is computed, we can compute it in a diagonal basis of eigenvalues $b_i$ (assuming $A$ is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues have no multiplicities), and then $\det B = \prod_{i= 1}^{n} b_i$, and therefore we obtain your formula.